# Prevent Android browser scaling on rotation without setting target-densitydpi to device-dpi

Tags: android, html, css, web-applications, mobile-website

Right now I'm using the following viewport meta tag:

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi, user-scalable=0" />
```

The medium dpi scaling seems to get the best results in terms of default legibility. On most pages, when I rotate between portrait and landscape, the scaling stays at that level, however, on pages where I have orientation media queries, a higher zoom level is triggered, which is not desired.

I know this *can* be resolved by using `target-densitydpi=device-dpi`, but on high-resolution Android phones this doesn't look good, so I'd prefer to keep the `target-densitydpi=medium-dpi`.

Am I correct in thinking that the above meta tag should lock the scaling at medium-dpi? Also, is there a way to prevent the scaling/zoom on rotation as described above?

Comment: higher zoom level is not desired by you, but may be helpful to people with sight problems

Answer (score 0):

With that below i never ran across you issue

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=0, initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
```